# Marian Trace D4 SRC not detect (alsa problem)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, alsa

I would like to use a Marian Trace D4 SRC (all AES digital card) with alsa (in the Alsa Matrix : FPGA) 
but  I can't see the card with qjackctl
with cat /proc/asound/cards : nothing also 
with lspci -v : it's ok but the name of the card is  not « audio controller » but « multimedia controller »

I have to install it with differents configurations :
Debian 8 Jessie 
Ubuntu 14 Trusty
and the last version of KXSTUDIO

I have tried a Kernel 4.1 and 4.2

Nothing to do.

Comment: ALSA's [matrix page for Marian cards](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Marian) shows no driver for the Trace D4.